# "IllegalStateException: No match found" when getting match group

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following code to extract street address, state, city and zip from txt.

```
public boolean parseGoogleAddress(Iterator<WebElement> iter)
{
    //String streetAddressRegex = "(?<=at\\s)\\d{3,5}\\s\\S*\\s\\w*.*?(?=,)";
    String stateRegex = "(?<=\\s)[A-Z]{2}(?=\\s)";
    String cityRegex = "\"(?<=,)\\s.{2,25}(?=,)\"";
    String zipRegex = "\"(?<=\\s)\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\]]\\]\"";

    String streetAddress;
    String state;
    String city;
    String zip;

    Pattern streetAddressPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=at\\s)\\d{3,5}\\s\\S*\\s\\w*.*?(?=,)");
    Pattern statePattern = Pattern.compile(stateRegex);
    Pattern cityPattern = Pattern.compile(cityRegex);
    Pattern zipPattern = Pattern.compile(zipRegex);



    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        WebElement webelementAddressList = iter.next();

        String singleAddress = webelementAddressList.getText();

        System.out.println("Value of singleAddress: " + singleAddress);

        Matcher streetAddressMatch = streetAddressPattern.matcher(singleAddress);
        Matcher stateMatch = statePattern.matcher(singleAddress);
        Matcher cityMatch = cityPattern.matcher(singleAddress);
        Matcher zipMatch = zipPattern.matcher(singleAddress);

        streetAddress = streetAddressMatch.group();
        System.out.println(streetAddress);


        System.out.println("streetAddressMatch: " + streetAddressMatch.group(0) + " stateMatch: " + stateMatch.group() + "cityMatch: " + cityMatch.group() + "zipMatch: " + zipMatch.group());
        break;
        }

    return true;

}
```

The  `"itr"` just contains a list of address similar to the one mentioned below.

I tried changing the variable to plain regex for `streetAddressRegex` (as you can see in code) but still I am not getting results.

Every time I run it I get something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
at ParseAddress.parseGoogleAddress(ParseAddress.java:45)
at ScrapeAddress.GoogleScrapeAddress(ScrapeAddress.java:73)
at Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

The regex patterns have been tested and work properly on their own.

An example of the text/address being passed to find regex patterns in is:

```
    Find Salvation Army Thrift Store at 269 Washington St, West Warwick, RI 02893-5910. Call them at (401) 828-6301
```

I changed         .group(0) to .group() but still did not work.

Am I compiling the patterns incorrectly? Pls advise.

Thanks

Comment: Quantifiers like `?` have to be escaped. `"(?<=\\s)[A-Z]{2}(?=\\s)"` The question mark is surely causing you problems, both in the first and the second group

Comment: I don't think question mark is the problem. If I try escaping it Eclipse start to complain

Comment: Escaping characters for a regex is done with a double slash - `\\ ` instead of a single one (like when you're escaping quotes - `\"`

Comment: I see.. but apparently this was not the issue as adding `find()` method worked as another person suggested.. But I still don't understand logic behind it

Comment: When you go to the restaurant and call the waiter you can't expect him to know what your order is, right? That's the same here - when you create a `Matcher` you can't expect it to know whether you want it to match the line instantly, or do another operation first. This is why you call either the `find()` or `match()` methods to do that...

Comment: I think if you are Googling on the error message, then this question is better phrased than the one that it was closed in favour of. Too much fluff in the other title. Wood from trees!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
streetAddress = streetAddressMatch.group();
```

You are calling `group()` without calling `streetAddress.find()` or `streetAddress.matches()` before.

Comment: Doesn't         'Matcher streetAddressMatch = streetAddressPattern.matcher(singleAddress);' take care of this? Maybe I'm missing something.. Do I need to call both?

Comment: `Matcher streetAddressMatch = streetAddressPattern.matcher(singleAddress);` just declares a `Matcher`. But you need to call either `find()` or `matches()` on this method to be able to populate all the groups.

Comment: But `matches()` returns a boolean value.. I don't see why it is required? Anyhow, I just tried it and it worked! But I don't understand why this step is required.. I will accept your answer.. If you could explain each step it will be better..

Comment: it doesn't, it just tells you whether there is a match or not...

Comment: As I said earlier only a `find / matches` call executes the regex again given input. `Matcher` object remains unpopulated otherwise hence `IllegalStateException`